# Python class Inheritance Initialization

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, initialization, multiple-inheritance

I have the following example setup:

```
class Feet:
   def __init__ (self, value = 0.0):
      self.value = value
      self.units = "f"

   def feet(self):
      return  self.value


class Meters:
   def __init__(self, value = 0.0):
      self.value = value
      self.units = "m"

   def feet(self):
      # This is probably not an accurate conversion.
      return  self.value * 2.54 * 10 


class Distance (Feet, Meters):
   def __init__(self, type = Feet()):
      Feet.__init__(self)
      Meters.__init__(self)
      print type.feet()   -- Prints 254.0
      self = type
      print self.feet()   -- Prints 254.0

dist = Distance(Meters(10.0))

print dist.units   -- Prints = "m"
print dist.value   -- Prints = 0.0
print dist.feet()  -- Prints = 0.0
```

I can't seem to understand why when I initialize the class to a Meters Class type, and assign it 10.0, I don't keep the 10.0. However the Units seem to have stayed correct. Am I missing something about how this is being setup?

My understanding is that I'm creating an "instance" of Meters, and assigning it to the "self" variable of Distance. If the self value couldn't be modified I could understand if my units was "f", but my units is "m" so it's obviously assigning the Meters class to self, but it's not taking the instantiated values, which I find quite odd.

To be honest I don't even know what I would google in this case, so I apologize I haven't done a whole lot of googling, most of what I found didn't apply at all to this type of problem.

Additionally, my plan was to basically "cast" it to the same type no matter what you passed in, for example for feet I would return the self instance for the Feet class, and in the Meters class I would return Feet(self.Value * 2.54 * 10) so I would always have my distance in Feet.

so for Feet feet becomes

```
def feet(self):
   return self
```

for Meters feet becomes

```
def feet(self):
  return Feet(self.value * 2.54 * 10)
```

To Recap, is there a reason that I'm able to pass in 1 of 2 classes as part of initialization, but it doesn't take my initialization parameters for that class?

It's really unclear to me why I can assign "self" in the distance class, and before it returns it *appears* to have the right initialization but upon returning it doesn't work right.

Comment: You are redefining all the methods. Your first two classes have the same methods. You are inheriting from both, so the second class's methods are overriding the first class's method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that you are inheriting from 2 classes Feet and Meters. Both classes have the same methods. In your `Distance.__init__()` method, you are overriding Feet's methods with Meters' methods when doing this:

```
  Feet.__init__(self)
  Meters.__init__(self)
```

What I would have done differently:

```
class Distance(object):
    def __init__(self, meters=None, feet=None):
        self.feet = feet
        self.meters = meters
```

Then you can do something like:

```
distance = Distance(meters=Meters(12))
print distance.meters.value
print distance.meters.type
# Here do whatever you want with them
```

You can pass in the two objects at the same time. And do some other stuff with
the two objects if the are both different than None.

Comment: When I remove both cases, I then have no "attribute" units, so how do I "init" the classes if that makes sense?   I just tried type.__init__(self) but then when I print "type.feet()" it comes out as unsuported operand type for * instance and float, but .value should be a float, not an instance.

Comment: You shouldn't inherit from 2 classes in that case, I'll edit my answer with another of doing it

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely no reason to inherit from either Feet or Meters here, let alone both. This is a classic case of composition, rather than inheritance, especially since you are passing the units class as a parameter. Remove that subclassing, and in `__init__` you can do `self.type = type`.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers cover the problems you have with inheriting, but haven't covered your rebinding of `self`.

Inside a method (such as `__init__`), `self` is simply a local name bound to the instance. You are perfectly at liberty to rebind the name, but that simply makes `self` refer to something else. *It doesn't affect the instance*.

In this case, when `__init__` returns the `self` name goes out of scope, but the original instance is assigned to `dist` just as though you hadn't rebound the name `self`.

Note that `__init__` is an initializer, not a constructor. Python does also allow you to define a custom constructor for a class (`__new__`), and the constructor can change the object that is returned. However you don't need to use it here.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
self = type
```

doesn't do what you think it does. You think this is an assignment statement, in which the object refered to by `self` takes on the attributes of `type`, a la C++.

Python doesn't have assignments in the same sense that other languages have.

What that line does is to bind the local name `self` to the object to which `type` is currently bound. It has absolutely no effect outside of `Distance.__init__()`, and virtually no effect on the object to which `self` was previously bound.